# sql query add 1 year, less days passed in month

Tags: mysql, intervals

I have a table with rows of dates,
I need to get rows for one year:

```
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(cal_date, '%e %M') as cal_date, price_client, 
price_owner, description FROM table WHERE cal_date < 
DATE_ADD('2017-09-13' , INTERVAL 1 year)
```

The result of this query are date rows with dates from 1 September 2017 until 12 September 2018.

I would like the result from 13 September 2017 until 12 September 2018.

Updated, This is the correct query, works like I wanted:
    WHERE cal_date >= '2017-09-13' and cal_date < DATE_ADD('2017-09-13' , 
    INTERVAL 1 year)

Comment: Change `DATEADD('2017-09-13'...` to be `DATEADD('2017-09-01'...`?  This of course assumes you have all records for those dates in that range.  (note all we did was change the 13 to 01)  But woudln't you also need to say `and cal_date>='2017-09-01'`?

Comment: Thanks, but the date are added dynamically and can be any day of the month, and I just thinking, and even can have diferent prices, so the result must be from 2017-09-13. Sorry, for this, I will edit the question.

Comment: `DATE_ADD('2017-09-13' , INTERVAL 11 month)`  Seems odd you want 11 months not 1 year so just add 11 months? 13 Sep 2017 to 12 Aug 2018 is 11 months.  or maybe add 1 year subtract 1 month.  Id' be concerned about 31 days in Jan and 28 in feb and action of the sort...

Comment: No, I want a year, its for displaying one years prices.
As prices in same month may vary, I believe the best is from today and one year until next year.

Comment: puf, I forgot to change August to September...sorry again, what a mess. Its correct now

Comment: I would like to see the results of your query produce what you say they do.  To me what you have does what you want; other than you need to add `and cal_date >= '2017-09-13'`  So far you handle < 1 year from date entered. but if cal date is 2 years ago, then it would be included, so you need to set the start and end dates.  `WHERE Cal_date>='2017-09-13' and Cal_date<DATE_ADD('2017-09-13' , INTERVAL 1 year)`

Comment: The problems is that I get from 1 september 2017....its 13th September today

Comment: On web query is displayed like this, looks bad:
1 September to 30 June low season, € 265.00/night
1 July to 31 August high season ,€ 278.00/night
1 September to 13 September low season, € 265.00/night

Comment: Yes, thats must be, and cal_date >= '2017-09-13 is missing, will try now

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your problem: http://rextester.com/WDXHE5921

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, stupid me

Comment: WHERE cal_date >= '2017-09-13' and cal_date < DATE_ADD('2017-09-13' , INTERVAL 1 year)
Thats the correct.....
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

for a generic format based  on curdate() you could use

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(cal_date, '%e %M') as cal_date
    , price_client
    , price_owner
    , description 
FROM table WHERE cal_date < 
      DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), interval 30 day), interval 1 day) , 
                                        INTERVAL 1 year)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work once you account for cal_date>= same date

you handled < future date but you didn't handle > or >= current date.  As it stands you will always return all records older than 1 year from today.  you have no lower boundary defined.

DEMO: http://rextester.com/WDXHE5921

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(cal_date, '%e %M%Y') as cal_date, price_client, 
price_owner, description 
FROM table
WHERE cal_date < DATE_ADD('2017-09-13' , INTERVAL 1 year) 
  and cal_date >= '2017-09-13';
```

This question would have benefited from [talking to the duck first](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/)